# ¿Cómo incluir archivos dentro y fuera de otro directorio?

Tags: php

Uno de los inconvenientes que estoy presentando es al ordenar el código php, donde cada funciones diferentes las guardo en una carpeta distinta, es curioso que dentro de esa carpeta se incluye todos los archivos de aquella aplicación y directamente desde ahí se puede ver resultados o hacer pruebas.

Ahora el problema es llamar aquella aplicación desde `public_html` que se encuentra enlazado el dominio.

Porque genera error diciendo que los `include` no están en el directorio `public_html` y es correcto, porque esos `include` están ordenados dentro de una carpeta.

Ejemplo de archivos ordenados en carpetas:
`public_html -> php -> visitas` dentro de la carpetas `visitas` tengo mis archivos `php` y otra carpeta de configuraciones `functions`.

**insertar_visitas.php**

```
include("functions/data.inc");
{
  //Mi archivo funcionando
}
```

Ahora si yo llamo ese archivo desde `public_html` me va generar error sobre que el archivo `include` no se encuentra en el directorio.

**index.php**

```
include("php/visitas/insertar_visitas.php");
{
  //Generando errores de advertencia 
}
```

En resumen como puedo incluir los archivos `include` según su existencia.

include "php/visitas/functions/data.inc"; y include "functions/data.inc";

Sí no existe en dicho directorio incluir el siguiente include

Algo así:

```
  include "php/visitas/functions/data.inc";
else {
  include "functions/data.inc";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes revisar esta funciones

```
<?
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."<br>";
echo dirname( __DIR__ );
?>
```

Mas info Variable Reservada http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php

Mas info Constantes PHP http://php.net/manual/es/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: Estaba navegando en la web para encontrar más información, entre ella el siguiente articulo indica [que es no recomendable usar root en include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048818/include-php-files-when-they-are-in-different-folders)

Comment: Si es mejor que se pueda resolver de forma relativa, es para dar un ejemplo de las posibilidades. Ademas pueden ayudarte a generar condiciones sin que salga directamente al cliente :)

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas incluir diferentes archivos segun su existencia puedes usar la función "file_exists()", ademas de usar una condicional. Por ejemplo:

```
if (file_exists("php/visitas/functions/data.inc")) {
  include "php/visitas/functions/data.inc";
} else {
  include "functions/data.inc";
}
```